# SVG - How to drop an inset shadow on a path that has an rgba fill?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

Assuming I have a circle shape (or any shape) in SVG with semi-transparent black fill (or any semi-transparent color):

```
<circle r="50" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" />
```

How can I drop a configurable (color, blur, position) inset shadow whose transparency is independent of the shape fill?

Note: I do not know anything about the background beforehand, the SVG must be really transparent, not faked.

[image]

Comment: Draw another circle.

Comment: Added an illustration of the effect and as you can see, I can't just draw another circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to do an inset-shadow - first resetting the source graphic's color to black/fully opaque.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="inset-shadow">
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 
        0 0 0 0 0 
        0 0 0 0 0 
        0 0 0 100 0" result="opaque-source"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
      <feOffset dy="10"/>
      <feComposite operator="xor" in2="opaque-source"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="opaque-source"/>
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <circle filter="url(#inset-shadow)" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" />
  
  <svg>
```

Or you can use a lighting effect to do this - more complicated, and performance can be pretty mixed.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="top-light">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 0 0 0 
        0 0 1 0 0 
        0 0 0 100 0"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      <feDiffuseLighting surfaceScale="200" diffuseConstant="1" kernelUnitLength="1" lighting-color="white" result="lightmap">
        <fePointLight x="100" y="0" z="10" />
      </feDiffuseLighting>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
      
    <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha" />
    
    // Insert another color matrix in here to recolor the shadow
     <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>

     
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <circle filter="url(#top-light)" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" />
  
  <svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of drawing a circle you draw a path representing a rectangle with a hole and apply the filter to this path.

What you see as a golden circle is in fact a rectangle drawn behind the shaded path.

```html
<svg viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" width="300"> 
  <defs>
    <filter id="f">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" result="desenfoque"></feGaussianBlur>
       <feOffset in="desenfoque" dx="3" dy="3" result="sombra"></feOffset>
       <feMerge>
         <feMergeNode in="sombra"></feMergeNode>
         <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
       </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect x="-100" y="-100" width="200" height="200" fill="gold" />
  <path fill="yellow" d="M-100,-100v200h200v-200h-200M50,0A50,50 0 0 1 -50,0A50,50 0 0 1 50,0z" filter="url(#f)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is clever, but the svg in my usecase is independent of the object and color behind it (which is a gradient) and cannot be a cutout.

Comment: I don't know how else I could specify it further, it seems to cut right to the chase, but I added a note that the SVG must be independent of whatever is behind it if that makes it any clearer.

Comment: I need to understand what part should be transparent? The circle in my code is in fact a hole: completely transparent.

Comment: The circle itself is semi-transparent over an unknown color background. I realize in your case it's actually a hole through a top layer that has a fill, and another color below it, but I don't know what that color is beforehand on either the top or bottom layer as you have it and I need the circle to have a semi-transparent fill (black or white in my case) to blend with the background. I might have solved it playing with some filters https://codepen.io/salsita/pen/qBbmYMw